# manipulating list items python

Tags: python, string

```
line = "english: while  french: pendant que  spanish: mientras  german: whrend "

words = line.split('\t')

for each in words:
 each = each.rstrip()

print words
```

the string in 'line' is tab delimited but also features a single white space character after each translated word, so while split returns the list I'm after, each word annoyingly has a whitespace character at the end of the string.

in the loop I'm trying to go through the list and remove any trailing whitespaces in the strings but it doest seem to work, suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Just `line.split()` could give you stripped words list.</s>

Updating `each` inside the loop does not make any changes to the `words` list

Should be done like this

```
for i in range(len(words)):
    words[i]=words[i].rstrip()
```

Or

```
words=map(str.rstrip,words)
```

[See the map docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#map) for details on map.

Or one liner with list comprehension

```
words=[x.rstrip() for x in line.split("\t")]
```

Or with regex .findall

```
words=re.findall("[^\t]+",line)
```

Comment: in the data im parsing that would for example split the french word "pendant que" into two words

Comment: Ok, then you could try with my second example `for i in range(len(words)): ...` or `words=map(str.rstrip,words)`

Comment: Ah, that works thankyou. I see python shares a few of the benefits of languages like haskell. In the map function is str.strip a constant in this case? Feels odd without a set of parenthesis...

Comment: @dave It's the name of the function to be called, with the arguments following. map will use that function on each of the elements in words. So map itself uses funcname( arg ) with funcname given by you, str.rstrip.

Comment: **downvote**? well, I just wouldn't mind. but would be great if there is an explanation though.

Comment: umm, if i was registered to vote it would have been up!

Last question: on the str.strip though could you please explain why it isn't string.strip() for example. I thought strip() was a part of the string.py module and is there any other conventions where you would type a method name without parenthesis?

Comment: @dave: Type it without parens when you want the function object itself, and with parens when you want the result of the function call.

Answer (score 1):

```
words = line.split('\t')
words = [ i.rstrip() for i in words ]
```

Comment: thats nice. i didnt realise python did list comprehensions

Comment: or you could even combine this into one-liner

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression:

```
import re
words = re.split(r' *\t| +$', line)[:-1]
```

With this you define the possible sequence  as the delimiter. It also allows more than one space because of the * operator (or no space at all).

EDIT: Fixed after Roger Pate pointed an error.

Comment: You'll still need to remove the last space (the last character in the string) after this.